# IBM MobileFirst 7.0 - Geofenceing in IBM MobileFirst

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-geolocation

How you will compare current mobile user with the Geofence area in MobileFirst Browser simualtor.

For example: I have created one Geofence area lets say circle shape. I decleared a varaible in that I stored that values like Longitude, Latitude and Radius. Now the task is how you will compare this value with the current user while moving in geo-location(Mobile device tracing location).

```
var myfence={longitude:2.2941741728805236,latitude:48.85817656827215,radius:100};
function getFirstPositionAndTrack() {
var geoPolicy = WL.Device.Geo.Profiles.LiveTracking();
geoPolicy.timeout = 60000; // set timeout to 1 minute
geoPolicy.maximumAge = 10000; // allow to use a position that is 10 seconds old
    WL.Device.Geo.acquirePosition(
        function(pos) {
            // when we receive the position, we display it and start on-going acquisition
            displayPosition(pos);
            var triggers = {
                Geo: {
                    posChange: { // display all movement
                        type: "PositionChange",
                        callback: function(deviceContext) {
                                displayPosition(deviceContext.Geo);
                            }
                    },
                leftArea: { // alert when we have left the area
                        type: "Exit",
                        circle:{
                            longitude: pos.coords.longitude,
                            latitude: pos.coords.latitude,
                            radius: 100
                        },
                        callback: function() {
                            var msg="Left the area";
                            alert("Left the area");
                            AdapterCalling("Vinod",msg);

                            WL.Client.transmitEvent({ event: 'exit area'}, true);
                        }
                    },
                    dwellArea: { // alert when we have stayed in the vicinity for 3 seconds
                        type: "DwellInside",
                        circle: {
                            longitude: pos.coords.longitude,
                            latitude: pos.coords.latitude,
                            radius: 100
                        },
                        dwellingTime: 3000,
                        callback: function() {
                            var msg="You are Still in the Vicinity";
                            alert('Still in the vicinity');
                            AdapterCalling("Vinod",msg);

                            WL.Client.transmitEvent({ event: 'dwell inside area'}, true);
                        }
                    }
                }   
            };

            WL.Device.startAcquisition({ Geo: geoPolicy }, triggers, { Geo: alertOnGeoAcquisitionErr } );
        },
        function(geoErr) {
            alertOnGeoAcquisitionErr(geoErr);
            // try again:
            getFirstPositionAndTrack();
        },
        geoPolicy
    ); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely clear on the question.

Note that the Mobile Browser Simulator allows you to simulate the device's location and movement, where wifi networks are located (including SSID and MAC address), and where there is no GPS reception. The location of geo-fence triggers is not controlled by the Mobile Browser Simulator at all, that is specified by the application's logic. To test the behavior, you should create an appropriate scenario in the Mobile Browser Simulator whereby the device's movement pattern will activate the geofence. For example, for a dwell trigger, you could have the device pass through the area quickly (to see that the trigger doesn't activate), then return to the area and stop for a sufficient amount of time, before leaving the area again.

Comment: @useruser2674117 Great answer. Even I tested in my simulator and partially working. But my question is all about how we will match the current user co-ordinates with the Business location co-ordinates there. Look at the above code I created myfence variable and how we will match this with the mobile moving co-ordinates.

Comment: What's the business objective you want to achieve? I'm not sure by what you mean by match. Do you want to know if the user coordinates fall within the circle defined by myfence?

Comment: Exactly. We need to create one or more geo-fence areas (Business areas) whenever user comes to that particular area we should match the user current co-ordinates with that business co-ordinates. if both are mathes then we need to send appropriate push notification to user. Here How we will match the current user co-ordinates with the business location?

Comment: So you should either be able to achieve this by utilizing an appropriate trigger, or you could consider using WL.Geo.isInsideCircle or WL.Geo.isInsidePolygon as appropriate. You can get the coordinates object from the device context received in the trigger callback; e.g. ctx.Geo.coords

Comment: So Second option is best one as it is API in MobileFirst. By using deviceContext we will get the current user location i.e, coordinate and we are creating circle. so by using passing these values to this method we will get exact resultent WL.Geo.isInsideCircle (coordinate, circle, options). Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Both are possible through the APIs (one uses the startAcquisition API with triggers, the other explictly uses isInsideCircle), it depends on what is easier for you to write.